# Springdoc with multiple api-doc in diferent URL and PATH

Tags: springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui, springdoc-openui, springdoc-ui

I have an api in java 8 with springboot 2.7.5 and springdoc-openapi-ui 1.7.0 version.

I have three controller in this api like this:

/controllerOne
(group = ControllerOne)

/controllerTwo
(group = ControllerTwo)

/controllerThree
(group = ControllerThree)

I want to separate the documentation so that each endoint sees its corresponding group in the corresponding url and path like this:

url1: http://app.domain.com/controllerOne/swagger-ui.html?group=ControllerOne

url2: http://app.domain.com/controllerTwo/swagger-ui.html?group=ControllerTwo

url3: http://app.domain.com/controllerThree/swagger-ui.html?group=ControllerThree

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance !!

I try to copy the dist folder into a folder in my proyect to personalice de urls, paths and index.html, but I do not work for me.
Thanks.